# How to insert another item programmatically into body?

Tags: python-3.x, google-calendar-api, document-body

I am trying to build a free/busy body request to Google Calendar API via Python 3.8 . However, when I try to insert a new item into the body request, I am getting a bad request and can't use it.

This code is working:

```
SUBJECTA = '3131313636@resource.calendar.google.com'

SUBJECTB =  '34343334@resource.calendar.google.com'


    body = {
  "timeMin": now,
  "timeMax": nownext,
  "timeZone": 'America/New_York',
  "items": [{'id': SUBJECTA},{"id": SUBJECTB} ]
}
```

Good Body result:

```
{'timeMin': '2019-11-05T11:42:21.354803Z', 
'timeMax': '2019-11-05T12:42:21.354823Z', 
'timeZone': 'America/New_York', 
'items': [{'id': '131313636@resource.calendar.google.com'}, 
{'id': '343334@resource.calendar.google.com'}]}
```

However,
While using this code:

```
items = "{'ID': '1313636@resource.calendar.google.com'},{'ID': '3383137@resource.calendar.google.com'},{'ID': '383733@resource.calendar.google.com'}"

  body = { 
  "timeMin": now,
  "timeMax": nownext,
  "timeZone": 'America/New_York',
  "items":  items 
}
```

The Body results contain additional quotes at the start and end position, failing the request:

```
{'timeMin': '2019-11-05T12:04:41.189784Z', 
'timeMax': '2019-11-05T13:04:41.189804Z', 
'timeZone': 'America/New_York', 
'items': ["{'ID': 13131313636@resource.calendar.google.com},{'ID': 
53333383137@resource.calendar.google.com},{'ID': 
831383733@resource.calendar.google.com},{'ID': 
33339373237@resource.calendar.google.com},{'ID': 
393935323035@resource.calendar.google.com}"]}
```

What is the proper way to handle it and send the item list in an accurate way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- In your situation, the value of `items` is given by the string of `"{'ID': '1313636@resource.calendar.google.com'},{'ID': '3383137@resource.calendar.google.com'},{'ID': '383733@resource.calendar.google.com'}"`.
- You want to use as the object by parsing the string value with python.

  - The result value you expect is `[{'ID': '1313636@resource.calendar.google.com'}, {'ID': '3383137@resource.calendar.google.com'}, {'ID': '383733@resource.calendar.google.com'}]`.
- You have already been able to use Calender API.

If my understanding is correct, how about this answer? Please think of this as just one of several answers.

#### Sample script:

```
import json  # Added

items = "{'ID': '1313636@resource.calendar.google.com'},{'ID': '3383137@resource.calendar.google.com'},{'ID': '383733@resource.calendar.google.com'}"

items = json.loads(("[" + items + "]").replace("\'", "\""))  # Added

body = { 
  "timeMin": now,
  "timeMax": nownext,
  "timeZone": 'America/New_York',
  "items": items
}

print(body)
```

#### Result:

If `now` and `nownext` are the values of `"now"` and `"nownext"`, respectively, the result is as follows.

```
{
  "timeMin": "now",
  "timeMax": "nownext",
  "timeZone": "America/New_York",
  "items": [
    {
      "ID": "1313636@resource.calendar.google.com"
    },
    {
      "ID": "3383137@resource.calendar.google.com"
    },
    {
      "ID": "383733@resource.calendar.google.com"
    }
  ]
}
```

#### Note:

- If you can retrieve the IDs as the string value, I recommend the following method as a sample script.

  ```
  ids = ['1313636@resource.calendar.google.com', '3383137@resource.calendar.google.com', '383733@resource.calendar.google.com']
  items = [{'ID': id} for id in ids]
  ```

If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize.